# What's best (fastest) way to get DOM elements in specific area

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get all DOM elements within a selector area (created when press and drag left mouse, like photoshop, illustrator, figma selector). as the following img:
[image]

[image]

All elements are absolute position with `left, top, width, height` attributes. And the selector given a rectangle with `left, top, bottom, right, width, height`. And please note that we have alot of elements (e.g: 10,000 DOM elements), so if we loop through all 10,000 elements to check if it with in selector area, that's not good idea.

I've tried 2 solutions:

1. Using `intersection-observer` to observer visible elements on screen first, then we only need to check in these elements.
2. Cache all elements with 4 objects:

   - byTops: store all elements with order `top` ascending
   - byBottoms: store all elements with order `bottom` ascending
   - byLefts: store all elements with order `left` ascending
   - byRights: store all elements with order `top` ascending

And when we check, it maybe faster

And this is DEMO for solution 1: [Demo for solution 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-moveable-with-full-drag-select-wb0so)

Does anyone have a better solution for this scene? Please help me!

thanks you very much!

Comment: on my machine iterating over and Array with 10,000 values takes about ~0.4ms

Comment: It's not only "iterating over", we must do alot of check operations. Every mouse move will generate a new area, and we must check over 10,000 elements for every mouse move.

Comment: iteration would be Ok unless the elements are very custom and big in term of memory space, if I can suggest a non-tested way, it would be a Drag/Drop in javascript, check this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API), and I would add action on `select element as dropped element` and catch the event on the elements that are underneath it.

Comment: Challenge accepted :) doing 4 comparisons per item (for 10,000) items takes ~1ms. Totally acceptable for interactive work

Comment: Can you share your machine information? I think this solution is not good for clients that owner weak computers.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the minimum size of each element they can select, you could potentially use [`document.elementFromPoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) to get the elements selected.

What I mean is, say they drew a selection, and each thing they can select is at least 40px x 60px.  You could then do something like:

```
let {top, left, right, bottom} = rectangleCoords;
const selectedElements = new Set();
for (let x = left; x <= right; x += 40) {
    for (let y = top; y <= bottom; y+= 60) {
        const el = document.elementFromPoint(x, y).closest('.thing-you-want');
        if (el) {
            selectedElements.add(el);
        }
    }
}
```